# Hibernate Filter - how to join child with parent to get only one child - can't pass the parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the below configuration between my Java Classes A, B with their associated tables being A1, B1. 
Table A1 has a one-many relationship with B1, defined in the database through the id column. 
B1 has a composite key. 
I am trying to define a filter in hibernate, such that after enabling the filter, when i query for A, in the result, i retrieve only one record of B matching the id and source fields/columns of A, and not the whole collection of B.

I was looking up solutions for even without defining a filter. Couldn't define a one-to-one in hibernate-mappings as database has a one-to-many relation defined between these tables. 
B1 table has to support multiple source records for an id, so we have the id/source in B1 defined as a composite key. 
But functionally, only one id-source combination of B is a valid record to go with A, and that's what I am trying achieve through this mapping.

I've been trying to see if in the filter, I could somehow join the table B1 with table A1 on the id/source of A1, so that I could pull that 1 record from B1. 
But I've not been able to figure out how.
I cannot pass in the id/source of A1 at runtime by using setParameter() on the filter, as A is a child of another Class C, having one-many relation between C and A. In the application, I query for C by its primary-key id1 to pull the whole-tree (object-tree: C -> A -> B) or (tables: C1 -> A1 -> B1).

```
getCurrentSession().enableFilter("exportedInvoiceFilter");
```

I know these 2 lines in the below snippet of code doesn't work, but I was trying to see if Hibernate-Filter could refine the results in this way, where i could filter/join by the 2 columns.

```
condition=":id = A1.d, :source= A1.source" />
```

The whole mapping is as below:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="C" table="C1">
    <id column="bId" name="bId" />
    <set name="a" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key>
            <column name="bId" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="A" />
    </set>
</class>

<class name="A" table="A1">
    <id column="id" name="id" />
    <property name="source" column="source"></property>

    <set name="b" lazy="false" fetch="join" table="B1" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="id"></column>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="B" />
        <filter name="filter1"              
            condition=":id = A1.id, :source= A1.source" />          

    </set>

</class>


<class name="B" table="B1">
    <composite-id name="key"
        class="D">
        <key-property name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="INT" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="source">
            <column name="source" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
</class>

<filter-def name="filter1">
    <!--<filter-param name="id" type="INT"/>
    <filter-param name="source" type="String"/>-->
</filter-def> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: please share the class C mapping used in the xml. And a valid xml mapping  showing all three classes A,B and C. In snapshot i can't see any ending </class> tags

Comment: still looks incomplete xml mapping. where is </class > etc. need a complete xml so as to recreate the scenario

Comment: the one you have provided along with the question <class name="A" table="A1"> ... <class name="B" table="B1"> , I need that one.

Comment: Hi, I was not able to post the whole code as a comment, so i edited my original post and placed the whole mapping on top of the original mapping. pls chk

Comment: that's what I need. Now its ok.

Comment: In your mapping xml, there is no definition for Class D used in  <composite-id name="key" class="D">. please add this. If you provide the POJOs of A,B,C, and D would be helpful.

Comment: The Class D is just for the primary key and is defined in java, it doesn't have a table and so no mapping.  Also, my main question is if we can really define (or not) the filter/condition in the above by joining A and B (with id/source columns) in some way in the above mapping, so that I don't retrieve the whole collection of B.   For this whole dao call, the only request parameter is the key "bId" for the class C.

Comment: I'm going to try this using hibernate/jpa query instead of filter. So that the data stored in db using C,A, B can be retrieved thro'  key "bId"or any other in future.